# How to prevent EF Core from creating DDD ValueObjects as tables

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I am using EF Core 5.0.1

I have created the following ValueObject

```
public class Address : BaseValueObject
    {

        public Address(string street, string zipCode, string city, string state, string country)
        {
            Street = street;
            ZipCode = zipCode;
            City = city;
            State = state;
            Country = country;
        }

        public string Street { get; set;  }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
        
        protected override IEnumerable<object> GetEqualityComponents()
        {
            yield return Street;
            yield return ZipCode;
            yield return City;
            yield return State;
            yield return Country;
        }

    }
```

and the entity which owns the value object

```
public class Location : BaseEntity
    {
        [Required]        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        
        public Address Address { get; set; }
    }
```

The Location object is configured as follows

```
public class LocationConfiguration : BaseEntityConfiguration<Location>
    {
        public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Location> builder)
        {            
            builder.OwnsOne(o => o.Address, a =>
            {
                a.Property(p => p.Street).HasMaxLength(600)
                    .HasDefaultValue("");
                a.Property(p => p.City).HasMaxLength(150)
                    .HasDefaultValue("");
                a.Property(p => p.State).HasMaxLength(60)
                    .HasDefaultValue("");
                a.Property(p => p.ZipCode).HasMaxLength(12)
                    .HasDefaultValue("");
            });

            base.Configure(builder);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that EF Core Migration is still creating ValueObjects as tables in the database.
What am I doing wrong?
In the generated migration code I can see the following:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Location",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    Name = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 80, nullable: false),
                    Timestamp = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", rowVersion: true, nullable: false, defaultValueSql: "CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Location", x => x.Id);
                });



migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Address",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    LocationId = table.Column<long>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    Street = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 600, nullable: true, defaultValue: ""),
                    ZipCode = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 12, nullable: true, defaultValue: ""),
                    City = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 150, nullable: true, defaultValue: ""),
                    State = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", maxLength: 60, nullable: true, defaultValue: ""),
                    Country = table.Column<string>(type: "TEXT", nullable: true)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Address", x => x.LocationId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_Address_Location_LocationId",
                        column: x => x.LocationId,
                        principalTable: "Location",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

and finally the DBContext class

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {        
        public PlannerDbContext(DbContextOptions<PlannerDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }                     
        
        public DbSet<Location> Locations { get; set; }        


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {            
            // do not use plural form for table names
            modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Configure(e => e.SetTableName(e.DisplayName())); 
                            
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);                                              

            modelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());            
        }
    }
```

Comment: It all looks fine to me.  The only oddity is that parameterless private constructor on the Address entity.  Do you get same result if you remove that?

Comment: And, not that it should make a difference, the static Create method is returning a Result<Address> instead of just Address.

Comment: How about use fluentapi in OnModelCreating in dbcontext :`modelBuilder.Entity<Location>().OwnsOne(c => c.Address, a =>{ //... });`

Comment: And in your context,delete code `public DbSet<Address> Address{ get; set; }`

Comment: @Yinqiu There is no DbSet<Address> Address{ get; set; }  in DbContext class. setting the configuration in OnModelCreating in dbcontext did not change anything

Comment: @NeilW, private constructor and Create method are a leftovers some experiments, I shall removed them in the given example (question updated)

Comment: Ah!  Just noticed, you're overriding the convention for ValueObjects and asking for a specific table name.

Comment: And now I see your answer below.  You got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason EF was creating tables for value objects was the part of the code where table naming convention is changed. I think, I have copied it from some  SO question about hot to set tables names in singular form.

This method `modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()` returns an enumerator to all objects from the model (including value objects). Configuring table name property against a value object will cause EF treat this type as an entity.

This part

```
            // do not use plural form for table names
            modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Configure(e => e.SetTableName(e.DisplayName()));
```

should be changed to

```
            // do not use plural form for table names
            modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes()
                .Where(x => !x.ClrType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseValueObject)))
                .Configure(e => e.SetTableName(e.DisplayName()));
```